# How to prevent hibernate from loading wrong dates?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, date, tapestry

The problem is I get the wrong date from DAO's load function.

The observed date is stored in the PostgreSQL database (comes from the birthdate column from the User table) and is equal to 1982-03-28. It is sometimes fetched as 1982-03-27. I got some tip from more experienced users and they say that it is somehow connected to timezone issues.

The wrong values come from the java.util.Date class' instance. I get them by the Calendar class' object. When I call this little one:

```
calendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()
```

it returns

```
Central European Time
```

The BirthDate column's type is:

> birthdate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

The value of the timezone variable set in the postgresql.conf file equals to Poland.

The load method's inner implementation looks like this:

```
public T load(ID aPrimaryKey, boolean aLock)
{
    if (aPrimaryKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter aPrimaryKey can't be null!");
    }
    preLoad(aPrimaryKey);
    T entity; if (aLock) {
        entity = _session.load(getEntityClass(), aPrimaryKey, LockMode.UPGRADE);
    } else
        entity = _session.load(getEntityClass(), aPrimaryKey);
    postLoad(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

My database version is

> PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian
>   4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

I use

> hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar

My entity class looks like this (has few more fields):

```
import javax.persistence.Column;

@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="User")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="userId", sequenceName="user_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class User {

   @javax.persistence.Id
   @Column(name="Id", nullable=false)
   @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy=javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO, generator="userId")
   private long id;

   @Column(name="Name")
   private String firstName;

   public User(String firstName, java.util.Date birthDate, java.util.Date registrationDate)
   {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.birthDate = birthDate;
       this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
   }

   @Column(name="BirthDate")
   @javax.persistence.Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
   private java.util.Date birthDate;

   @Column(name="RegistrationDate", nullable=false)
   @javax.persistence.Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private java.util.Date registrationDate;

   public String toString()
   {
       return firstName + " should clean himself...";
   }

   public User() {}
}
```

I changed the type of `birthdate` field to `TIMESTAMPTZ` - then everything appears to work well. But how to solve to problem without changing the column's data type? Do you have any tips?

Comment: How is PG storing it as a timestamp and not a date? Weird. Can you change the column definition to store it as a date and not a timestamp?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I could, but I already have few thousand users in the database, so I would have to change the birth dates for all of them (I will check how Date differ from Timestamp in PostgreSQL, because I am not pretty sure how to convert between these two types).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that your system is set to `CET`, but Poland is currently on `CEST` (and Pg honors DST).

A couple things you can do:

- Use `SET TIME ZONE timezone;` at the beginning of each session to make sure it matches your client.
- Use `AT TIME ZONE` when selecting the values - or the function `timezone(zone, timestamp)` - to match the client.
- Cast the value to `timestamptz` when selecting, so TZ information is preserved (not actually sure about this one).

But really, it's much better to always use `timestamptz` to store time.

To answer your question from the comment: you can just cast `timestamp/tz` values to the `date` type (`birthdate::date`). `date`s have no time information and are not timezone dependent, so you'll always get the value as-is.

This may actually make more sense - you probably *do* want to see birth dates in their original time zones (ie as the users entered them), not converted to the current TZ.